# Getting issue while generating .so files

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am generating .so files from c file using ndk-build command.

i am getting the below error

```
 undefined reference to `bcopy'
 clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

searched on stackoverflow. got some solutions. but none of them fixing the issue.

Could anyone please help me out on this?

Comment: You're using the bcopy function, but aren't providing an implementation anywhere.  Usually caused by not linking the proper library.  Or you could always just change bcopy to memcopy.  bcopy is considered legacy at this point

Comment: @GabeSechan For memcopy also same issue

Comment: Please post the relevant code and makefile(s).

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan Its working... Thanks a lot!!! You saved my time... But small correction, its not "memcopy" its a "memcpy".

Answer (score 2):

As per the suggestion from Gabe Sechan,

```
  Use "memcpy" instead of "bcopy".
```